# Why is the effective base resistance important for the voltage divider BJT amplifier?

Tags: bjt, biasing

I came across many questions regarding the below type of biasing where they explain and analyze Rth Vth and conclude that Rth must be very small comparing to Rin. Rin is the effective resistance seen by the input. I have made the following drawing for transformation of the input as follows:

[image]

I can understand that the bigger the Rth the more we will have voltage drop across Rth. Some call it loading and say that it affects stiffness. I dont get it why. Everything is constant irrespective of the value of Rth. Isn’t it?

I cannot really explain myself why it matters as long as we calculate all the node voltages. Can you give an example where we can see that the relative value of Rth to the Rin matters?

If possible a simulation would help.

Comment: In short for good DC bias stability we need a "stiff" voltage divider. Wich in terms of an Rth means that  Rth << (beta +1)*Re.  But nothing is for free. Low Rth lowers the amplifier AC input impedance.

Comment: I read this” Wich in terms of an Rth means that Rth << (beta +1)*Re “ everyehere. But why? I dont get it. Why it is not stiff when Rth is large? What happens when Rth is large can u give an example? Is that about distortion?

Comment: Do you know the equation for a voltage divider?

Comment: Yes I know. What Im struggling is what is the consequence of Rth being large.

Comment: The voltage divider with a high Rth is not a "stiff" voltage divider. Any load resistance connects to this voltage divider will change the voltage divider output voltage.   On the other hand, "stiff" voltage divider has a low Rth hence the output voltage does not change that much with the load connected to it?  Is that clear for you?

Comment: And why we need a "stiff" divider you can read for exampel here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/451441/transistor-design-with-beta-variation/451448#451448 and here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/124776/stiff-voltage-divider-bias-for-an-emitter-follower/124782#124782

Comment: Yes I knew that the divider will change the voltage divider output voltage but it will do for all components of a superpositioned signal. But Im asking what are we losing here? That would not distort the signal, if Rth is large it would only decrease the amplified output, Is that it?

Comment: Does it mean if Rth = Rin the output will be halved comparing where Rth = 0?? Is that the reason?

Comment: No, we are talking here about the DC bias condition (quiescent current stability). The problem is that we do not know the exact value of a BJT beta and also we do not know the exact value of a Vbe voltage. And that both of this beta and Vbe will vary from transistor to transistor, with temperature, current and so on. So to overcome this problem we use a stiff voltage divider (low Rth). Hence, the collector current is set by a "stiff" Ve voltage and Re resistor.

Comment: But from the AC signal point of view low Rth value lowers the AC signal input resistance seen by the signal source (increases the loading effect on a signal source). And this low Rth together with a signal source resistance reduces the amplifiers gain (another voltage divider but this time for AC signal).

Comment: I see I was thinking completely wrong directions. I need to read more about the theory.

Comment: @Genzo You **always** have to keep at least two minds (maybe more) on the BJT stage. The DC operating point and the AC behavior. For the DC operating point, you want stability against variations in ambient and operating temps, stability against variations in parts that will be used, stability against power supply (battery) changes in voltage or source impedance, drift of parts over time, and if you are being peevish about it, the current phase of the moon. However, you also must accept that no matter what you do, the DC operating point must also be allowed some range over which it works well.

Comment: @Genzo For AC, you'll worry about input impedance loading (which may change with the signal), variations in gain due to signal changes (distortion), and of course the gain you do want. These *also* vary with temperature, part variations, etc. You also have noise to consider, parasitic capacitance and inductance, and more. You start with what you know must be well managed and work out from there. For some, it may be that it's a 9 V battery with 2 Ohm series impedance that should work down to 7 V and 10 Ohm series impedance, for example. Other situations will have different priorities.

Comment: @Genzo You might consider looking [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/373625/38098) or [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/375269/38098).

Answer (score 2):

> Everything is constant irrespective of the value of Rth. Isn’t it?

Nope.

That \$\mathrm{R_{in}}\$ depends on the transistor \$\beta\$ (\$\mathrm{H_{FE}}\$, whatever), and \$\beta\$ varies a lot from transistor to transistor, as well as varying somewhat with temperature*.

So you want the bias network to be "stiff" so that your lovely circuit that works in the lab with a few transistors that all happen to come from the same batch will still work in production when many transistors are being purchased from different companies, and possibly different transistor part numbers are being substituted, or the inevitable process changes are being made at the various manufacturers.

* I just realized I don't know how much -- hmm; something I need to learn!

Comment: What do you mean by works fine?

Comment: I didn't say "works fine"!  By "works" I mean "does what it's supposed to do".  Products that don't work often disappoint customers, who, in turn, tell their friends, who then don't buy that product.

Comment: Typically the \$\beta\$ will increase/decreases by 1% per degree.